# How can I convert " r part" partial correlation into Cohen's d?

Tags: meta-analysis

How can I convert " r part" partial correlation into Cohen's d ? I'm calculating Cohen's d to get effect sizes to do meta-analysis . I'd appreciate if someone would give me the direct equation.or detailed examples.

Comment: Correlation effect size is normally expressed in terms of Cohen's q. Did you mean that?

Comment: Exactly, as we could convert pearson's correlation coefficient r or squared R to Cohen's d  . Can we use the same calculation to convert parial r too?